# Lines tangent to the given curve

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Could you help me describe the set

$A = \{ (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ : \  \text{curves} \ ax+by = 1 ,  \ x^m + y^m = 1 \ \ \text{are tangent} \}$, $m>1, \ a, b , x, y>0$

I know that the equation of the tangent to a curve $f$ at the point $x_0$ is

$y-f(x_0) = f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$

$y=\frac{a}{b}x + \frac{1}{b}$ is supposed to be tangent to $y=f(x)=(1-x^m)^{\frac{1}{m}}$

$f'(x)= -\frac{1}{m}(1-x^m)^{\frac{1-m}{m}}mx^{m-1}$

$\frac{a}{b}x + \frac{1}{b} = -\frac{1}{m}(1-x_0^m)^{\frac{1-m}{m}}mx_0^{m-1}(x-x_0) + (1-x_0^m)^{\frac{1}{m}}$

and

$\frac{a}{b}x_0 + \frac{1}{b} = (1-x_0^m)^{\frac{1}{m}}$

Those are just my thoughts.

Could you tel me how to solve it correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: sorry which line is  tangent of which?or they both are tangent to some other one?

Comment: They are supposed to be tangent to each other.

Comment: no one could be tangent of another,both be tangent to each other  i dont know if it is possible

Comment: ok in this case it means that slope of $y=a*x/b+1/b$ must be same as slope of $X^m+y^m=1$

Comment: Well, I'm still not sure how to formulate my answer (description of the set) :)

Comment: you should say that  set of tangent line is all the  lines  at every point except  at  this points,where slope is not equal $a/b$ and free term $1/b$,in your case $x_0=1$ and $x_0=x$

Comment: But what about the set of pairs $(a,b)$?

Comment: without   explicit points,how can you say?you can say in generally,they are all point    where  right side equation has meaning and at the same time right side $x_0$ and $m$ are all the point   depend on which we can find $a$ and $b$,in humabn language you can't say more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok we have that    from the  first line

$f(x)=(1-x^m)^{1/m}$

and slope  of this at point $x$ is

$f'(x)= -\frac{1}{m}(1-x^m)^{\frac{1-m}{m}}mx^{m-1}$

and $y=a*x/b+1/b$

then both slopes  should be equal to each other,which means that

$f'(x)$ at point $x$ must be same as  $a/b$,dont we have some specific value of $x_0$ or $m$ ? and of course free term is same as $1/b$,according to equation of tangent line

$y=k*x+b$

EDITED:

example find tangent of $y=x^2$ at point $x_0=2$

$f'(x_0)=2*x_0=4$

so we have

$y-f(x_0)=f'(x_0)*(x-x_0)$

or  $y-4=4(x-2)$

or $y=4*x-4$

that means that if this is tangent of curve  $y=f(x)$,then $f'(x)$ at some point $x_0=2$ must be equal to $4$,free term we found after inserting known point

EDITED:
also pay attention that  $x_0$ does not equal to $1$,because in this case slope is  $0$,which is impossible   as neither  $a$ or $b$ are zero

Comment: Do you mean that we have too little data to describe the set?

Comment: we can describe generally,we can't find  explicit value of $a$ and $b$ untill  value of $m$ and $x_0$  point or  at which point we are looking tangent  line are not given

Comment: i have updated my answer

Comment: Could you help me describe it generally, then?

Comment: ok you can say that  $y=a*x/b+1/b$  is could be  tangent line of $x^m+y^m=1$ except point $x_0=1$ or $x_0=x$,this points are easy to  see,maybe there is other points as well

Comment: I think that y = - a x / b + 1 / b would be better (even if this does not change much). Cheers.

Comment: yes if minus move to left side,yes both is possible

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici welcome thanks for point this

Comment: @datodatuashvili. It is amazing that nobody noticed this small ridiculously insignificant detail !

Comment: everything happens,@ClaudeLeibovici